# Is it possible to serialize this?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have these classes.
Store is the smallest piece, but it holds all the data.
I also have Game which has List of stores.
Store also has Progressbar,Labels,Button, how can I (de)serialize it so that each object corresponds with the specific controls and data.

```
[Serializable]
    public class Game
    {
        public static int Money { get; set; } = 111111110;
        public static int Gold { get; set; } = 250;
        public List<Store> Stores { get; set; }

[Serializable]
    public class Store
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Interval { get; set; }
        public int Num_Upgrades { get; set; } = 0;
        public double BaseCost { get; set; }
        public int BaseMoney { get; set; }
        public int MoneyMaking { get; set; }
        public int BaseInterval { get; set; }
        public int CostOfUpgrade { get; set; }
        public int IntervalReducer { get; set; } = 1;
        public int EarnMultiplier { get; set; } = 1;
        public CustomProgressBar ProgressBar;
        public Button UpgradeButton;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Timer Timer;
        public Home HomeForm { get; set; }
        public Label Label { get; set; }
        public Label EarnLabel { get; set; }
        public bool Clicked { get; set; } = false;
        public bool IsBought { get; set; }
        public bool hasManager { get; set; } = false;
        Random random = new Random();

public static Game game { get; set; }
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            Deserialize();
        }
```

I mean it works but all I have is this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzTvk.png)

[Github](https://github.com/malle2002/ProjectVP)

Comment: ...and you're serializing that how exactly?

Comment: And to/from where? And when? When I keep state in a Winforms app, I deserialize at the end of FormLoad and I tuck stuff way in Closing. I have some old code that writes to IsolatedStorage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/isolated-storage)

Comment: No. You can't serialize controls/components. Serialize their serializable creation/state/data properties.

Comment: You can serialize any class using binary serialization, but you need to write methods to load your controls from the classes.

Comment: You need to extract the non-UI (and therefore serialisable) properties into a separate DTO ("Data Transfer Object") class that  you use only for serialisation. Then write code to create the DTO from your `Store` class and code to create your `Store` class from the DTO.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume your "store" class is some type of UI class, it it has buttons etc.

You should most likely not try to serialize any UI classes, since UI classes has a whole bunch of logic attached to them, and this tend to complicate serialzation/deserialization. This is also true for most other classes that contain large amounts of logic.

What you should probably do is to create separate classes specifically for Data Transfer, often called [DTOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). These are classes *without* any logic at all. You can then use a library to serialize your DTOs, for example using [Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0), but there are plenty of other alternatives if you prefer something else.

Depending on your design it might require some code to copy values from your DTO to your UI or vice versa, and while this might increase the amount of code, it tend to be very straightforward code to write and maintain.

Comment: What do i need StoreDto ? the problem are the controls all I need is their data(location,name) so that we know the Store has those controls from the UI. Do i need to make Dto for every control then write function for (de)serialization. which means game needs to have List<StoreDto> which might contain ControlDto?

Comment: @memelordtimelord Yes, you will most likely need a hierarchy of dtos. This might or might not directly correspond to your UI classes. Keep in mind that you most likely will properties in your UI that represent temporary state, like your random variable, that should not be serialized. You might also want to take a look at how WPF works, since it uses a binding model that helps separate the UI from the data.